# REST spring services and JQUERY web integration best practices

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, architecture

Regarding to the best way to design a system using spring-mvc (REST services) and jQuery . I think exists the following approaches.

1. One war file in which you have spring services and jQuery stuff, with this approach we have all the domain objects available to be used with spring-mvc, we can create initial jsp pages and then refresh some elements using jQuery calls to our services.
2. Two war files, one having the spring services and the other contains spring-mvc stuff and jquery, in this case the creation of pages could be done by jsp pages and also refresh elements with jquery calls to our services, but to make this possible we need to have a common library of domain objects to be used in the second war, also internally use restTemplate in some controllers that need to be created (It sounds like duplicate code).
3. Have one war file running the REST services and a other “package” without any java or spring stuff only jquery, it means all the call and information retrieval must to be done using jquery, initial jsp pages creation cannot be done with this option and all the content are obtained via REST services. (no need of use internal controllers to call services by java)

Thinking about it I realized that one and second have the following disadvantages.

- Have services and web stuff in the same war file sound like a bad idea thinking in SOA, the movement of this war will result in move unneeded jquery and web stuff.
- Have jsp and jquery stuff mixed not sound like a good idea but I think is a common practice (I wonder why?), using this I think we need to create some controllers in the second war to initially create the web pages, go using restTemplate to obtain initial information and then update or refresh using jquery calls. It feels that a have a controller just to retrieve data to the services, why don’t go directly …

> I just want to implement the third approach but the question is: there is any disadvantages that I’m not seeing or any
>   advice that I should know before use that approach? Also there is any suggestion to handle this kind of systems it will be great to hear something from you, coming from java and jquery developers

Comment: To me it seems like you are looking at two different ideals, The Spring application that hosts your API, and a front end application that can be hosted anywhere... I would write the 'JQuery' application and host it on... anything, enable xsite on your java app, and just call your rest urls. If you want to use spring to build a front end app. thats fine, but if you want spring to host rest... have it host rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that version 3 gives you the most flexibility and is what you would typically see in the design world.

Treat the rest and the front end as separate applications entirely. If done correctly, you can have a very robust application capable of proper agility.

- Version 1: Load the page in an initial controller call, and use jquery to make subsequent service calls. All code exists within one package.

  The disadvantage is tight coupling. You are now restricted to the language of your api, and no longer providing a service based approach to your data and services.

  I have seen this version applied mostly when the application developer cares more about async front end calls than a SOA based language.
- Version 2: Have a war containing Spring Services, and a war for the JS.

  The issues with this method can be overcome with the use of a jar instead of another server application. Though this approach is commonly used, the draw backs are still reliance on external packaging.

  Using a jar that contains all the code to hit databases and create domain objects separate from the code that the controllers use to serialize and respond to web requests creates a very clean way to manage your api, however this creates a complexity and an extra component that can be avoided using version 3. It also gives the same odd behavior you see in version 1.

  I have seen this approach taken by teams developing pure api applications. I have not seen this done on teams that also require a front end component. Method one or three has been used in these cases.
- Version 3: Create an application that deals with just the front end responsibility Create an application that handles the server side responsibility.

In both version 2 and version 3, separate your service calls from your http calls. Make them different because it allows modularity.

For instance, we need to respond to http Requests

```
@Controller
class MyController{
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
    @GET
    public String getData(String dataId){
       return service.getData(dataId);
    }
}
```

and we need to respond to active mq requests

```
 Message m = queueReceiver.receive();
 if (m instanceof DataRequest) {
     DataRequest message = (DataRequest) request;
     queueSender.send(service.getData(request.getDataId())); //service call
 } else {
     // Handle error
 }
```

Also, it gives you the ability to manage what you need to handle on the http side different from your service side.

```
@GET
public String getData(HttpRequest request, String dataId){
   if(!this.handleAuth(request)){
      throw new 403();
   }
   try{
      return service.getData(dataId);
   catch(Exception e){
      throw new WrappedErrorInProperHttpException(e);
   }
}
```

This allows your service layer to handle tasks meaningful to just those services without needing to handle all the http crap. And lets you deal with all the HTTP crap separate from your service layer.

Comment: I think you understand part of my point but not at all and I'm agree with you that REST services can run in the server and nothing else there, and I can call those services using jquery in another front end application. But why some apps use spring-mvc + jquery to do the process, it is enough to use only pure jquery to do that, based on that which are the advantages or disadvantages we could have in the two approaches ?. It should be any reason for the exitence of the second approach. (mix spring-mvc and jquery) to call rest api

Comment: I see no reason to use both... In my experience (which is limited) I have yet to see this done. RestTemplate is made for client calls in the server... If RestTemplate is being used to make calls to an internal api inside the existing controller... I would be very confused as to why this was done. If JQuery is present, in a jsp.. that makes sense becuase the browser would load all the data, and make http calls to the server after the data was loaded. Which would make sense... but to chain them ... JQuery ---> Controller --> rest call --> controller --> JQuery, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I see your question now... Sorry about that. Let me clarify my answer.

Comment: Let me know if I answered your question. I can make a better stab at it and find some documentation if that doesn't address it.

Comment: But in version2, without involve restTemplate how you can create the initial page *information in the first user hit*, if there are two wars and the database is only connected to the REST API, it is why you need to call those REST services using resttemplate and obtain initial info, then you can update with jquery calling REST api directly, why this approach is used ?

Comment: Ohh I see that does make sense. I personally wouldn't solve the problem with rest template. though that solution works just fine. My thought would be to create a jar representing the service layer and import it in the rest layer instead of making a call to a war. ill update my answer.